# Related entries in Matrix field

Tags: entries, matrix, relations

I have three sections:

1. Discography
2. Performers
3. Works

Within "Discography", a Matrix field contains related entries from "Performers" and from "Works".

I am looking to display those related entries in Discography with the code below, but nothing happens (no error, no display):

```
{% for entry in craft.entries.section('Discography').order('title') %}

    {{ entry.title }}

    {% for block in entry.discoOeuvres %}

        {% set relatedWorks = craft.entries.section('Works').relatedTo(entry) %}
        {% set relatedPerformers = craft.entries.section('Performers').relatedTo(entry) %}

        {% for work in relatedWorks %}
            {{ work.title }}

            {% for performer in relatedPerformers %}
                {{ performer.title }}
            {% endfor %}
        {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Also tried to follow [this solution](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/2287/how-can-i-display-related-entries-selected-within-a-matrix-field), with no success...

Where do I miss something?

Thanks for helping.

Comment: I haven't dealt with this specifically, but I know that the relationship is with the `matrix block` and not the `entry`. Have you tried `relatedTo(block)`? (untested). The answer on the page you linked is also correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Douglas mentioned in the comments, if the relation is defined within a Matrix block, then the Matrix block is the source of the relation; not the entry.

Soy you just need to change `relatedWorks` and `relatedPerformers` to:

```twig
{% set relatedWorks = craft.entries.section('Works').relatedTo(block) %}
{% set relatedPerformers = craft.entries.section('Performers').relatedTo(block) %}
```